# Swift 4, Json data doesn't appear in cells

Tags: json, xcode, swift4

I can't put data to the cells, I searched in different tutorials and it should work , I checked in debug area and data are downloaded but doesn't exist in cells, I tried also with custom cells but it doesn't work too. I have not got any error message, simply empty cells. Do you know maybe what can cause  this issue? I spended much time for searching solution but I can't find anything, on every tutorial people do this similar to me.

```
struct Country: Decodable {
   let name: String  
}

class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var countries = [Country]()
    var liczba = Int()

    @IBOutlet var tv: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        json() {
            self.tv.reloadData()
        }

        tv.dataSource = self
        tv.delegate = self
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return liczba
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = countries[indexPath.row].name
        return cell
    }

    func json (completed: @escaping()->()) {
        let jsonUrl = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
        let url = URL(string: jsonUrl)

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, response, error) in
            do {
                self.countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data!)
                let numer = self.countries.count
                self.liczba = numer
            }
            catch {
                print("error")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are having a problem with the sequentiality of your code. You are calling reloadData on your tableview but at that moment you don't have set the datasource yet.

try this:

```
tv.dataSource = self
tv.delegate = self

json() {
    self.tv.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never calling the `completed` closure of your `json` method, so `self.tv.reloadData()` will never be executed.

Add `completed()` after `self.liczba = numer`.

Comment: Works! but I got runtime error. UITableView.reloadData() must be used from main thread only. What does it mean

Comment: All UI methods have to be called from the main thread (you might want to read about threads and concurrency), and URLSession calls it's handler outside the main thread. Wrap the completion code around a main thread dispatch like this: `DispatchQueue.main.async { completed() }`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not returning anything from the closure I recommend to delete the completion handler and reload the table view on the main thread **within** the closure.

And don't forget to handle a potential error

```
func json() {
    let jsonUrl = "https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all"
    let url = URL(string: jsonUrl)

    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { [unowned self] (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error { print(error); return }
        do {
            self.countries = try JSONDecoder().decode([Country].self, from: data!)
            self.liczba = self.countries.count
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tv.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print("error")
        }
    }.resume()
}
```

and call the method in `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tv.dataSource = self // I'd connect datasource and delegate in Interface Builder
    tv.delegate = self
    json()
}
```